# contractInstance.methods.issueTokens is not a function

Tags: solidity

I am trying to issue a transaction from my UI using metamask and web3 to a deployed contract on ropsten. Whenever I go to send the transaction with the required uint input, I get "contractInstance.methods.issueTokens is not a function". The ABI and address are getting passed in properly, so I'm not sure what's happening.

Here is the contract to deploy:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

import "../CheckERC165.sol";
import "../standard/ERC721.sol";
import "../standard/ERC721TokenReceiver.sol";
import "../libraries/SafeMath.sol";

/// @title A scalable implementation of the ERC721 NFT standard
/// @author Andrew Parker
contract TokenERC721 is ERC721, CheckERC165{
    using SafeMath for uint256;


    //Tokens with owners of 0x0 revert to contract creator, makes the contract scalable.
    address internal creator;
    //maxId is used to check if a tokenId is valid.
    uint256 internal maxId;
    mapping(address => uint256) internal balances;
    mapping(uint256 => bool) internal burned;
    mapping(uint256 => address) internal owners;
    mapping (uint256 => address) internal allowance;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => bool)) internal authorised;


    /// @notice Contract constructor
    /// @param _initialSupply The number of tokens to mint initially
    constructor(uint _initialSupply) public CheckERC165(){
        creator = msg.sender;
        balances[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        maxId = _initialSupply;

        //Add to ERC165 Interface Check
        supportedInterfaces[
            this.balanceOf.selector ^
            this.ownerOf.selector ^
            //this.safeTransferFrom.selector ^
            //Have to manually do the two transferFroms because overloading confuse selector
            bytes4(keccak256("safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256"))^
            bytes4(keccak256("safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256,bytes"))^
            this.transferFrom.selector ^
            this.approve.selector ^
            this.setApprovalForAll.selector ^
            this.getApproved.selector ^
            this.isApprovedForAll.selector
        ] = true;
    }

    /// @notice Checks if a given tokenId is valid
    /// @dev If adding the ability to burn tokens, this function will need to reflect that.
    /// @param _tokenId The tokenId to check
    /// @return (bool) True if valid, False if not valid.
    function isValidToken(uint256 _tokenId) internal view returns(bool){
        return _tokenId != 0 && _tokenId <= maxId && !burned[_tokenId];
    }


    /// @notice Count all NFTs assigned to an owner
    /// @dev NFTs assigned to the zero address are considered invalid, and this
    ///  function throws for queries about the zero address.
    /// @param _owner An address for whom to query the balance
    /// @return The number of NFTs owned by `_owner`, possibly zero
    function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint256){
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    /// @notice Find the owner of an NFT
    /// @param _tokenId The identifier for an NFT
    /// @dev NFTs assigned to zero address are considered invalid, and queries
    ///  about them do throw.
    /// @return The address of the owner of the NFT
    function ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns(address){
        require(isValidToken(_tokenId));
        if(owners[_tokenId] != 0x0 ){
            return owners[_tokenId];
        }else{
            return creator;
        }
    }

    /// @notice Mints more tokens, can only be called by contract creator and
    /// all newly minted tokens will belong to creator.
    /// @dev This function is optional, it isn't required by the ERC721 spec,
    /// and is not needed if the initial supply of NFTs is all that is needed.
    /// @dev Throws if msg.sender isn't creator, or if added tokens overflows maxId (uint256)
    /// @param _extraTokens The number of extra tokens to mint.
    function issueTokens(uint256 _extraTokens) public{
        require(msg.sender == creator);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(_extraTokens);

        //We have to emit an event for each token that gets created
        for(uint i = maxId.add(1); i <= maxId.add(_extraTokens); i++){
            emit Transfer(0x0, creator, i);
        }

        maxId += _extraTokens; //<- SafeMath for this operation was done in for loop above
    }

    function burnToken(uint256 _tokenId) external{
        address owner = ownerOf(_tokenId);
        require ( owner == msg.sender             //Require sender owns token
            //Doing the two below manually instead of referring to the external methods saves gas
            || allowance[_tokenId] == msg.sender      //or is approved for this token
            || authorised[owner][msg.sender]          //or is approved for all
        );
        burned[_tokenId] = true;
        balances[owner]--;

        //Have to emit an event when a token is burnt
        emit Transfer(owner, 0x0, _tokenId);
    }


    /// @notice Set or reaffirm the approved address for an NFT
    /// @dev The zero address indicates there is no approved address.
    /// @dev Throws unless `msg.sender` is the current NFT owner, or an authorized
    ///  operator of the current owner.
    /// @param _approved The new approved NFT controller
    /// @param _tokenId The NFT to approve
    function approve(address _approved, uint256 _tokenId)  external{
        address owner = ownerOf(_tokenId);
        require( owner == msg.sender                    //Require Sender Owns Token
            || authorised[owner][msg.sender]                //  or is approved for all.
        );
        emit Approval(owner, _approved, _tokenId);
        allowance[_tokenId] = _approved;
    }

    /// @notice Get the approved address for a single NFT
    /// @dev Throws if `_tokenId` is not a valid NFT
    /// @param _tokenId The NFT to find the approved address for
    /// @return The approved address for this NFT, or the zero address if there is none
    function getApproved(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address) {
        require(isValidToken(_tokenId));
        return allowance[_tokenId];
    }

    /// @notice Query if an address is an authorized operator for another address
    /// @param _owner The address that owns the NFTs
    /// @param _operator The address that acts on behalf of the owner
    /// @return True if `_operator` is an approved operator for `_owner`, false otherwise
    function isApprovedForAll(address _owner, address _operator) external view returns (bool) {
        return authorised[_owner][_operator];
    }




    /// @notice Enable or disable approval for a third party ("operator") to manage
    ///  all your assets.
    /// @dev Emits the ApprovalForAll event
    /// @param _operator Address to add to the set of authorized operators.
    /// @param _approved True if the operators is approved, false to revoke approval
    function setApprovalForAll(address _operator, bool _approved) external {
        emit ApprovalForAll(msg.sender,_operator, _approved);
        authorised[msg.sender][_operator] = _approved;
    }


    /// @notice Transfer ownership of an NFT -- THE CALLER IS RESPONSIBLE
    ///  TO CONFIRM THAT `_to` IS CAPABLE OF RECEIVING NFTS OR ELSE
    ///  THEY MAY BE PERMANENTLY LOST
    /// @dev Throws unless `msg.sender` is the current owner, an authorized
    ///  operator, or the approved address for this NFT. Throws if `_from` is
    ///  not the current owner. Throws if `_to` is the zero address. Throws if
    ///  `_tokenId` is not a valid NFT.
    /// @param _from The current owner of the NFT
    /// @param _to The new owner
    /// @param _tokenId The NFT to transfer
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) public {
        //Check Transferable
        //There is a token validity check in ownerOf
        address owner = ownerOf(_tokenId);

        require ( owner == msg.sender             //Require sender owns token
            //Doing the two below manually instead of referring to the external methods saves gas
            || allowance[_tokenId] == msg.sender      //or is approved for this token
            || authorised[owner][msg.sender]          //or is approved for all
        );
        require(owner == _from);
        require(_to != 0x0);
        //require(isValidToken(_tokenId)); <-- done by ownerOf

        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _tokenId);

        owners[_tokenId] = _to;
        balances[_from]--;
        balances[_to]++;
        //Reset approved if there is one
        if(allowance[_tokenId] != 0x0){
            delete allowance[_tokenId];
        }
    }

    /// @notice Transfers the ownership of an NFT from one address to another address
    /// @dev Throws unless `msg.sender` is the current owner, an authorized
    ///  operator, or the approved address for this NFT. Throws if `_from` is
    ///  not the current owner. Throws if `_to` is the zero address. Throws if
    ///  `_tokenId` is not a valid NFT. When transfer is complete, this function
    ///  checks if `_to` is a smart contract (code size > 0). If so, it calls
    ///  `onERC721Received` on `_to` and throws if the return value is not
    ///  `bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"))`
    /// @param _from The current owner of the NFT
    /// @param _to The new owner
    /// @param _tokenId The NFT to transfer
    /// @param data Additional data with no specified format, sent in call to `_to`
    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId, bytes data) public {
        transferFrom(_from, _to, _tokenId);

        //Get size of "_to" address, if 0 it's a wallet
        uint32 size;
        assembly {
            size := extcodesize(_to)
        }
        if(size > 0){
            ERC721TokenReceiver receiver = ERC721TokenReceiver(_to);
            require(receiver.onERC721Received(msg.sender,_from,_tokenId,data) == bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)")));
        }

    }

    /// @notice Transfers the ownership of an NFT from one address to another address
    /// @dev This works identically to the other function with an extra data parameter,
    ///  except this function just sets data to ""
    /// @param _from The current owner of the NFT
    /// @param _to The new owner
    /// @param _tokenId The NFT to transfer
    function safeTransferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _tokenId) external {
        safeTransferFrom(_from,_to,_tokenId,"");
    }


}
```

Here is my web3 api code:

```
     import React from 'react';
    import etherDiamond from './img/ether-diamond.gif';
    import Web3 from 'web3';
    import { getWeb3State } from './api';
    const {
      REACT_APP_ERC_721_ADDRESS: ERC_721_ADDRESS,
    } = process.env;

    const pMHashTokenArtifacts = require('./abi/ERC721ABI.json');
    const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io'));
    const contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(pMHashTokenArtifacts, ERC_721_ADDRESS);



    export const getEntityData = async entityId => {
      try {
        const responseTokenName = await contractInstance.methods.getTokenName(entityId).call();
        const tokenName = responseTokenName.valueOf();
        const tokenUrl = "http://localhost:3000/" + tokenName + ".png";
        return {
          id: entityId,
          name: tokenName,
          image_url: tokenUrl,
          url: `http://localhost:3000/`,
          color: '#333333'
        };
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return undefined;
      }
    };

    export const createHash = async name => {
  const { from, web3 } = await getWeb3State();
  const contractInstance = new web3.eth.Contract(pMHashTokenArtifacts,  ERC_721_ADDRESS);
  console.log(ERC_721_ADDRESS);
  console.log(pMHashTokenArtifacts);
  console.log(contractInstance);
  await contractInstance.issueTokens.sendTransaction(name, function(error, success) {
      if(error) console.log("Something wrong happened: " + error); 
      else console.log("Everything is all right: " + success); 
  });
};
```

Comment: What is your web3 version? The syntax has changed a bit between versions as far as I remember

Comment: "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.35" is the version I am using

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude `.methods` and use `contranctInstance.issueTokens.sendTransaction(arguments here, function(error, success){...});` and I think it should be all right.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82248/discussion-on-answer-by-pollux-contractinstance-methods-issuetokens-is-not-a-fun).